# Neo4j: is it a in-memory graph database?

Tags: neo4j, in-memory-database

I have worked with bit older version of Neo4j i.e. 1.8.x. **both embedded and REST mode**. but I never heard that it store data in-memory. Recently I've been through Neo4j [page](http://www.neo4j.org/develop/tools/jdbc) which says 3 different type of access to neo4j viz:

1. neo4j server i.e. REST mode
2. embedded mode
3. **in-memory**

**How Neo4J works with data in-memory** ? and when it was implemented ? was it there from older version i.e. 1.8.x ? or just added in newer version ? any additional changes required in configuration such as Spring data neo4j ?

**My findings**
I've heard about in-memory database that they handle most of the task in-memory i.e. RAM. for e.g. **VoltDB** and **[Redis](http://redis.io/topics/faq)**. (for optimized performance).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Neo4j features a stripped down variant called ImpermanentGraphDatabase. This one is intended to be used for testing only. E.g. when you develop a graph enabled application your unit tests might use it. **It is not recommended to use ImpermanentGraphDatabase for real life scenarios with large amounts of data.**

To use ImpermanentGraphDatabase you typically start with [`TestGraphDatabaseFactory`](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/master/community/kernel/src/test/java/org/neo4j/test/TestGraphDatabaseFactory.java), this one resides in the `neo4j-kernel` jar with classifier `tests`, see in the [reference manual](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/tutorials-java-unit-testing.html) as well.

Regardless if you're using Neo4j in embedded or server mode, multiple layers of caches get used to make your queries as fast as possible, for details look in the [reference manual](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/configuration-caches.html) as well.

To sum up: Neo4j is a transactional, ACID compliant graph database benefitting from your provided amount of RAM by caching. But I won't consider this being a in-memory database.

Comment: Can you please update the reference manual link for configuration cache ? Link is no longer exist now.