# Using Neo4j ImpermanentGraphDatabase for real life scenarios with large amounts of data

Tags: graph, neo4j, in-memory-database

I use Neo4j to do calculations on complex graphs from data stored on a relational database, these calculations must be done frequently so the natural solution has been to use Neo4j to create impermanent neo4j graphs on the fly.

I continue to find references like the one below on the internet ([Neo4j: is it a in-memory graph database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25481353/neo4j-is-it-a-in-memory-graph-database)):

> Neo4j features a stripped down variant called
>   ImpermanentGraphDatabase. This one is intended to be used for testing
>   only. E.g. when you develop a graph enabled application your unit
>   tests might use it. It is not recommended to use
>   ImpermanentGraphDatabase for real life scenarios with large amounts of
>   data.

I'm doing exactly the above, using ImpermanentGraphDatabase for a real life scenario with thousands of nodes on which I do on the fly calculations.
Creating an embedded database each time I need to do a calculation on the fly is not feasible so what solution does Neo4j offer for this scenario? what exactly happens if you use Neo4j ImpermanentGraphDatabase for real life scenarios with large amounts of data?

Answer (score 0):

There is the little word 'not' in the text.

Also in the (free) book "Graph Databases" ([download](https://neo4j.com/graph-databases-book/)) impermanent server mode is only recommended for testing, NOT for productive environments. If you want to use your graph locally (no cluster), you might use the embedded mode. Keep in mind, that there are always two parts for graph dbs: storage and traversal engine. But I think, you're looking for a (cypher) queryable datastructure? It's worth to have a look at TinkerPop/Gremlin ([link](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.1.0-incubating/#_tinkerpop3)).

For your purpose it depends on the part that'll change. The structure of your data? The formula for calculation? Or just the values? If your graph is static, you just need to update your data (not the graph database). If your graph is dynamic you might optimize your algorithm and use different data-structures. A graph is not always the best choice, neither are trees, lists or dictionaries.

Comment: Both data and structure change, as I said "Creating an embedded database each time I need to do a calculation on the fly is not feasible", a graph in my case is the best choice to represent relations.